# Second parameter in menu url (hook_menu) not working

Tags: 7

I have a problem in my hook_menu() function. When I try to catch a second parameter (%foo) in a url, fails.

My urls:

```
 $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-factors'] = array(
    'title' => 'Factors',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('forms_grade_factors_create_factor'),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'weight' => 5,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/factors'] = array(
    'title' => 'Factors',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('forms_grade_factors_create_factor'),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'weight' => 1,
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/ranges'] = array(
    'title' => 'Ranges',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('forms_grade_factors_create_range'),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'weight' => 2,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/delete/%webform_component/factor'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('forms_grade_factors_delete', 1),
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

When I typed in the browser a url, for example, http://drupal.dev/node/12/webform-factors/factors/1/delete, doesn't call *forms_grade_factors_delete* function. Instead, it's redirected to the default local task ('node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/factors').

'node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/delete' works fine. However, when I put another parameter, it fails (like 'node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/delete/%webform_component').

Another thing I don't know if it is correct is that (as you can see in the picture below), the tab without title (it corresponds to 'node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/delete/%webform_component/factor'), has within the url the string *%webform_component*.

[image]

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I don't understand why, but in the end I gave up and use the pattern:  "'node/%webform_menu/webform-factors/delete/%/XYZ'"

Comment: If you want to call `http://drupal.dev/node/12/webform-factors/factors/1/delete` your menu path must look like `node/%/webform-factors/factors/%/delete`.

Comment: Hi Huelfe. My question was why my _Auto-Loader Wildcards_ (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) are not working if I typed two or more of them. :(